# Registration in Rails

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am attempting to create a new user in rails.  There is a username, email, password and password confirm field on the new user form.  When I click on the create user button on the web page, the new_user form simply refreshes and the user is not added to the database.

Here is the code for my register method in the authentication controller

```
def register
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.valid?
   @user.save
   session[:user_id] = @user.id
   flash[:notice] = 'Welcome.'
   redirect_to sign_in_url
  else
   render :action => "new_user"
  end
```

end

This is my new_user form:

```
<p>Sign Up</p>
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => new_user_path, :method => :put do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label 'username:' %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= show_field_error(@user, :username) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'email:' %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= show_field_error(@user, :email) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'password:' %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= show_field_error(@user, :password) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label 'password confirmation:' %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <%= show_field_error(@user, :password_confirmation) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign Up' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <%= f.submit 'Clear Form', :type => 'reset' %>
</p>
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: is this routes defined in routes, update the qsn with your routes table.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `new_user_path` in your form references the url to `User#new` if you have defined `resources :users` in your `routes.rb` file. You will need to replace `new_user_path` with `register_user_path`, if you have defined `register` in your routes file. Double check for the path with by running `rake routes`, though.

From what I can see, there is no need to use have the register action. It'd make more sense to use RESTful actions `new`, `create`, `index`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy` in your case, since your logic follows the intuition behind them. Rails makes this convention easy to follow. See the routing Rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more.